# Backing up a postgresql database table with python in lambda

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am attempting to write a python script which will run in AWS Lambda, back up a PostgreSQL database table which is hosted in Amazon RDS, then dump a resulting .bak file or similar to S3.

I'm able to connect to the database and make changes to it, but I'm not quite sure how to go about the next steps. How do I actually back up the DB and write it to a backup file in the S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that worked for me was to create an AWS data pipeline to back up the database to CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Depending how large you database is lambda may not be the best solution. lambdas have limits of 512MB tmp disk space, 15 minute timeouts, and 3008 MB memory. Maxing out these limits may also be more expensive then other options.

Using EC2 or fargate along with boto or the aws cli may be a better solution. Here is an blog entry that walks through a solution

https://francescoboffa.com/using-s3-to-store-your-mysql-or-postgresql-backups

Comment: That almost works, the problem is that I don't have a server from which to run the backup script he suggests.

Comment: @user10028246 As I alluded to in my answer, the lambda solution depends on you database. Can you provide more information like how large it is? If you're using aws can you not spin up an ec2 instance? how often do you need to back it up? can you run it locally? in any scenario, the methodology will be the same, whether its running a lambda, ec2, fargate, or locally.